# How do I remove Bing from my new tabs page on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, bing

Bing is now in my new tabs page, apparently the result of some hack, which I removed.  I deleted the Bing Bar but Bing is still on my new tabs page.  How do I remove it?

Comment: Now that you've ventilated your frustration, can you provide some details?  What kind of hack and how did you remove it?  What is the new tabs page and in what way is Bing on it?  Which version of IE?

Comment: Is bing set as your home page?

Answer (score 0):

Go to internet options then under general tab you will see a button called "Tabs" click it. You will see a drop down box under a label called "When a new tab is opened, open" Try changing the option to a blank   page.